# How to get OpenCV 4.5.0 error message with cv::imread?

Tags: opencv

I'm discovering OpenCV and reusing a piece of code that use `cv::imread()`.

I want to print an error message when it fails, I can detect if there was an error but I can't get the reason of this error. Same for `cv::VideoCapture`.

I enabled verbose logging and I still get no error when I try to open a file that doesn't exist.

So, how can I get the error that caused `cv::imread()` to fail ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print an error message when it fails, I can detect if there was an error but I can't get the reason of this error. Same for cv::VideoCapture.

Well you can start with detecting which class gives an error. For instance, you can use `sys.exc_info()`

> I enabled verbose logging and I still get no error when I try to open a file that doesn't exist.

Here is an example:

```py
import cv2
import sys

try:
    img = cv2.imread('not_avail_img.png')
except:
    print("Error: {}".format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
```

Result:

```sh
Error: <class 'cv2.error'>
```

So, the result says the error is thrown from the `cv2.error`

> So, how can I get the error that caused cv::imread() to fail ?

If we re-design our code:

```py
import cv2

try:
    img = cv2.imread("not_avail_img.png")
    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
except cv2.error as err:
    print("Error: {}".format(err))
```

Result:

```py
Error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/Downloads/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Now there is no direct way to find `imread` error (as far as I know), but if you interpret the error `Assertion failed size.width>0 && size.height>0`, the problem is caused by the `img` variable, since `img` is `None`.

You can use `cv2.error` for finding and detecting `cv2` related errors.

Comment: I can do that by checking if the returned matrix is not empty (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56). This way I know there *was* an error but not *which*.

Comment: Then check it with returned matrix is not empty. Why do you ask the question?

Comment: I want to know the underlying reason of the error, instead of printing `Failed to load image`, I would to print something like `Failed to load image : Is a directory` or `Failed to load image : Bad data in the stream` to let know the user what really went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered another similar issue that happened in calling `cv::VideoCapture video(Path_to_video)`. `video.is_open()` got false and no detailed error msg show up.

I got the deep reason through the `errno` like below codes showing.

```
errno = 0;
cv::VideoCapture videoCapture(file);
if (!videoCapture.isOpened()) {
    slog::info << "Cannot open " << file << ": " << strerror(errno) << slog::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I got the error msg like this

```
 Cannot open xxx.mp4: Inappropriate ioctl for device.
```

Finally I solved this OpenCV problem through this error msg.

I think `cv.imread` must call Linux system API `read()`, and will set `errno` when failure happened.

More detailed info please refer to below link.
https://github.com/yangwang201911/open_model_zoo/blob/d596c069d5d5342e6d97ce6605992d26d007cd43/demos/security_barrier_camera_demo/cpp/main.cpp#L772

Comment: Although I don't want to rely on this side-effect. That's better than nothing.